# How to use named routes when using FriendlyId at the root path in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing, friendly-id

I have a basic `Page` model in `Rails` that I'm using with [FriendlyId](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) to allow admins to create pages like `"/about"` or `"/contact"`.

I have the following in my routes file (`config/routes.rb`) to ensure that the slugs for each page appear at the root of the site, such as https://example.com/about, etc:

```
resources :pages, except: [:show]
resources :pages, only: [:show], path: "/"
```

The problem is, with this approach, I can't use the normal named route like `page_path(@page)` in my views(or tests or controllers for that matter) because that routes to `"/pages/about"` and I get a `"No route matches [GET] pages/about" error.`

I could do both routes in my routes file so that `"/pages/about"` and `"/about"` work like this:

```
resources :pages
resources :pages, only: [:show], path: "/"
```

But, that creates an `SEO` duplicate content problem. I suppose I could create a helper that sets the `rel="canonical"` url for each page in the `html` header, but that also feels like a hack. I'd prefer for there to just be 1 version of each page at the root and also have a named route such as `"page_path"` or `"root_page_path"` that I can use throughout my app.

The hack I've come up with for the time being is `<%= link_to "#{page.slug}" %>`, but not having a named route seems very brittle.

What is a more "correct" way to do this in `Rails`?

I expected something like this to work:

```
resources :pages, only: [:show], path: "/", as: "page"
```

But that doesn't work either. Nothing in the [Rails guide on routing](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) is really helping either.

Answer (score 0):

You need top switch the order of their definitions:

```
resources :pages, only: [:show], path: "/"
resources :pages, except: [:show]
```

`resources` only give name to the first path with given url. However - you will have the problem now as the `pages/:id` path (for delete and update) has now no route helper (as it is normally the same as `show`).

EDIT: As mentioned in the comment - it will also automatically match `/pages` path to a show action with `id` equal to `pages` - not a great idea! Which leads to better option:

```
resources :pages, except: [:show]
get :id, to: "pages#show", as: :root_page
```

Which gives you `root_page_path(@page)` helper for `:show` action and `page_path(@page)` for `:update` and `:delete`

Comment: The order here is actually wrong. You need to declare the index route first as `/pages` would end up getting routed to the show action.